# Flash URLLoader and Location -redirection

Tags: flash, location, redirect, urlloader

I have a Flash object that sends an URL request with URLLoader. However, how do I make it follow those Location: redirections in headers?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, flash's url requests will follow redirections properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [URLRequestHeader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html).  There are examples on the livedocs page there too.